# Amazon alexa auto sdk integration in windows

Tags: android, alexa-skills-kit

I have downloaded the amazon alexa auto sdk, and build it in the linux environment. I have a windows environment in which I have android studio. Is it possible to build the sample app provided in the sdk in the windows environment using the created sdk.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the pre-built Alexa SDK here:
https://github.com/alexa/aac-sdk/releases

You have to copy *aace-release.aar* in *aac-sdk-1.2\samples\android\app\src\main\libs*

Then follow the instructions how to create an API key and put it in *aac-sdk-1.2\samples\android\app\src\main\assets*. You can put an empty api_key.txt file there as well - it won't stop compiling but some features won't run.

You will also have to (per instructions) download *login-with-amazon-sdk.jar* and put it in *aac-sdk-1.2\samples\android*

**Now you should be able to compile the sample app in Windows environment.**

In order everything to run fine you may have to edit *src/main/assets/app_config.json* and put there clientId, clientSecret, and productId that you got while creating your app key.

Comment: I m implementing the same but I could not be able to find out aace-release.aar file. Please help me with the same